# Display a list of sub-pages of Custom Post Type Parent Page

Tags: custom-post-types, php, shortcode, child-pages

I am trying to display the sub-pages of a custom page on the parent page. I found an abbreviated code that works very well for standard WordPress post_type "pages", but does not work for custom publishing types.

Here's the short code code I put in my functions.php file:

```
function v_list_child_pages() { 

  global $post; 

  if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )

     $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
  else
     $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );

  if ( $childpages ) {

     $string = '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';
  }

  return $string;

}

add_shortcode('v_childpages', 'v_list_child_pages');
```

---

If I place the shortcode[v_childpages] on a post_type "page" with children, it successfully displays all subpages in the linked list. But if I add it in a custom post_type, it's not like that.

Any advice or suggestion is welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the problem I was having.

In the `else` section I set `post_type` as an argument:

```
 $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'post_type=name-custom&sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The third line of your code specifies the `page` post type by checking if `is_page()`. You can change that to `is_singular('your-post-type')` so that it runs, then in your call to `wp_list_pages()` you also need to add a `post_type` argument so that that part of the code knows what to look for.

So, to have this shortcode work on both Pages and your specific CPT, sub in your post type's registered name in both places below where `uve_courses` appears:

```
function v_list_child_pages() { 
    global $post;
    // for Pages with a parent
    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
    // for individual CPTs with a parent
    } elseif(is_singular('uve_courses') && $post->post_parent ) {
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'post_type=uve_courses&sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );
    }
    if ( $childpages ) {
        $string = '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';
    }
    return $string;
}
add_shortcode('v_childpages', 'v_list_child_pages');
```

If you have additional CPTs you want this to work on, you will need to add additional `else` clauses to pass those post types.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I have applied the changes you recommended but I still don't get anything out of it... 
I did the above guided by this article: [link](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-a-list-of-child-pages-for-a-parent-page-in-wordpress/)

Comment: What is the name of your custom post type? This code depends on having the correct (usually lowercase) post type in 2 places - one in `is_singular` and one in the `wp_list_pages` line right below it.

Comment: I have put the name of my custom post type, which is the one that appears in the url:

    http://localhost/wordpressv/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=uve_courses

Comment: Updated the answer above - there are 2 places to sub in your `uve_courses` post type. While you're making edits, it's often helpful to make a CPT name singular - like `uve_course` - so that in certain functions you can tell whether you're dealing with a single post or group of posts.

Comment: You may also want to remove `sort_column=menu_order` from the `uve_courses` conditional if your post type doesn't have a `menu_order`... which I suspect is the case.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried everything, I'm literally busting my head to figure this out..

Comment: And your post type is hierarchical, and you have published at least one post that has a parent?

Comment: It's hierarchical, and if I've published it.
As I said before, in a normal post they are listed without any problem, but in a custom-post-type they no longer listed.